# How to Update Dataframe based on Results of Another Dataframe Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes called **channels** and **videos**.

I need a way to update videos > website column instances based on information stored and matched within channels > Website column instance.

ID's to use are:

- Dataframe channels: ID
- Dataframe videos: Channel_id

### Dataframe: channels

```
Channel       ID        Website   
=========     =====     =======
Company A     A0001     a.com
Company B     A0002     b.com
Company C     A0003     c.com
Company D     A0004     d.com
```

### Dataframe: videos

```
Category    Channel_id    Channel_name   website
========    ==========    ============   =======
Comedy      A0003         AAA
Action      A0004         BBB
Horror      A0008         CCC
Comedy      A0001         DDD
Comedy      A0044         EEE
Comedy      A0002         FFF
```

### Required Output

```
Category    Channel_id    Channel_name    website
Comedy      A0003         AAA             c.com
Action      A0004         BBB             d.com
Horror      A0008         CCC
Comedy      A0001         DDD             a.com
Comedy      A0044         EEE       
Comedy      A0002         FFF             b.com
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this?

```
result = pd.merge(videos, channels[['ID', 'Website']], how='left', left_on='Channel_id', right_on='ID').drop(columns='ID').fillna('')
```

Output

```
  Category Channel_id Channel_name Website
0   Comedy      A0003          AAA   c.com
1   Action      A0004          BBB   d.com
2   Horror      A0008          CCC        
3   Comedy      A0001          DDD   a.com
4   Comedy      A0044          EEE        
5   Comedy      A0002          FFF   b.com
```